# VSTO Outlook: Detect when Outlook is being closed

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a custom task pane placed at the top. Since I cannot hide close button nor the context menu, I decided to show a message to the user when he/she tries to close it saying that the task pane cannot be closed.

I show this message when the task pane visibility changes to false (it is the only way I can detect if user is trying to close it), so within the VisibleChanged event handler I show a messagebox.

```
this.myCtp = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myControl, "myTitle", this.Window);
this.myCtp.VisibleChanged += myCtp_VisibleChanged;


private void myCtp_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here is show my messagebox
{
```

The problem with this is that when Outlook is exiting, this messagebox appears to the user and I do not want this. So what can I do to prevent the messagebox to appear when Outlook is exiting?

I have thought of using a boolean variable that is set in the Application Quit event handler and then this variable is consulted in the myCtp_VisibleChanged event handler and according to this show or not the messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also trap the `Explorer.Close` event - if it is the last Explorer (`Application.Explorers.Count = 1`), you know Outlook is closing.

Comment: But keep in mind there can be situations when Outlook opens without any Explorers, but only with an inspector (e.g., when a user clicks a mailto link), so tracking inspectors closing and checking both the number of explorers and inspectors might be useful.

Comment: I did it but i see that instead of 1 as you said it is 0, so it would be Application.Explorers.Count = 0

Comment: So I guess Outlook removes the explorer from the `Application.Explorers` collection prior to the `Close` event firing..

Comment: Yep, it seems to. I have put a breakpoint in the first line of the Explorer Close event and Application.Explorers.Count returns 0. I am using Office 365. I don't know if depending on the Outlook version it can vary.

Comment: In case of an inspector window, it behaves different, I mean, in the inspector close event, the Application.Inspectors.Count = 1 (If there is an explorer opened)